# c# override method with more specific type declaration

Tags: c#, methods, types, overriding, abstract

Is there a way to implement the following logic in C#? *(note: the following code does not compile)*

```
abstract class Foo {
    void Bar(Object obj);
}

class SubFoo<T> : Foo {
    override void Bar(T obj);
}
```

Notice how `SubFoo` overrides the `Bar(..)` method with a more specific parameter type.

Comment: dynamic is its own thing, you cannot override it with a `T`

Comment: Why not declare base class as generic instead of using dynamic?

Comment: @maccettura @GiladGreen i changed it to `Object` .. since I don't know how to do it I'm still looking for the right way to achieve this

Comment: @TobiasWürth you still didn't answer the question why would you override it that way ?

Comment: You might want to read on the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-an-example-of-the-liskov-substitution-principle)

Comment: @Leftpanda imagine pipes you can connect building a pipelien with the following class declaration `Pipe<TIn, TOut>` ... imagine the following pipeline `Pipe<?,TA>` <-> `Pipe<TA, TB>` <-> `Pipe<TB, ?>` .. how do you define the `Connect(Pipe)` method without limitting yourself but still having a typesafe declaration at compile time?

Comment: @TobiasWürth there must be a common properties on the in and out as well you can create an interface and use it ?

Comment: @Leftpanda no the idea is that you can build a pipeline and the pipeline can change the type. aka process the input. i guess there is no interface which would cover all different types and their combination in use

Comment: @TobiasWürth and then why you don't want to make the base class generic ?

Comment: @Leftpanda because I want to connect them (e.g. linked list) and by that want to have a non-generic, but plain class to be able to define lists like `List<Pipe>` .. doing this with generics would limit me by not allowing me to insert different types. e.g. `List<Pipe<String, Int32>>` would not work if I had a different pipe type I'd like to insert into this list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't the override must have the same signature as the original. There are several alternatives:

**Make the base class generic**

```
abstract class Foo<TArg>
{
    public abstract void Bar(TArg obj);
}

class SubFoo<T> : Foo<T>
{
    public override void Bar(T obj) { }
}
```

**Leave the original function and add an overload**

```
abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract void Bar(object obj);
}

class SubFoo<T> : Foo
{
    public void Bar(T obj) { }
    public override void Bar(object obj) => this.Bar((T)obj);
}
```

**Use an interface instead of an abstract class to hide the less specific overload**

```
interface Foo
{
    void Bar(object obj);
}

class SubFoo<T> : Foo
{
    public void Bar(T obj) { }

    void Foo.Bar(object obj) => this.Bar((T)obj);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do that. Imagine this code:

```
Foo myFoo = new SubFoo<string>();
```

`myFoo` is is a `Foo` which takes an object, but it is actually an implementation of SubFoo which takes a string. So what would you expect to happen when you call

```
myFoo.Bar(1);
```

Foo.Bar takes an object, so you can pass in an integer, but SubFoo expects a string not an integer. The world blows up.